# How to do HTTP CONNECT Method by HTTPClient behind Proxy

Tags: java, android

I am programing a Browser using `HTTPClient` to access HTTPS on Android.
The following source code has implemented access HTTPS by `HTTPClient`.

```
  // Proxy Host and Port
  String proxyHost = "127.0.0.1";
  int proxyPort = 10000;
  // HTTPS Site
  String strURL_https = "https://172.17.4.37:8443/apache.html"; 
  URL url_https = null;
  HttpClient httpClient = null;
  HttpGet get = null;
  try{
    url_https = new URL(strURL_https);
    MySSLSocketFactory sf = MySSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();              
    get = new HttpGet(strURL_https);
    try {

      HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
      HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
      HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

      // Add two scheme for Port 443 and 8443        
      httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", sf, 443);
      Scheme sch2 = new Scheme("https", sf, 8443);
      httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
      httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch2);
      // Set Proxy   
      httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));

   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();           
   }
   HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
   // Execute GET Method
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get, context);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   String charSet = null;
   String contentType = null;
   StringBuffer sb = null;
   if(entity!= null){
     charSet=EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity);
     contentType=entity.getContentType().getValue();
     InputStream is = entity.getContent();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf8"));
     String text = null;
     String line = br.readLine();
     sb = new StringBuffer();
     while(line != null) {
       sb.append(line+"\r\n");
       line = br.readLine();
     }
   }
   // Load Data on Webview
   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(strURL_https, sb.toString(), "text/html", charSet, null);
```

But when do `httpClient.execute(get, context)`, my proxy server will receive HTTP CONNECT Method as the following:

```
CONNECT 172.17.4.37:8443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Host: 172.17.4.37:8443
```

My proxy server send the HTTP Method to VPN, but cannot get any response.
In my opinion, I should get like `HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established`.

My question is how to do `HTTP CONNECT` Method by `HTTPClient` without proxy.
After create connection established, set proxy to `HTTPClient`.

I am looking forward your answer.

Thank you.

Comment: I got some info from HTTP Tunnel Wikipedia. The client asks an HTTP Proxy server to forward the TCP connection to the desired destination using the "CONNECT" HTTP method. The server then proceeds to make the connection on behalf of the client. Once the connection has been established by the server, the Proxy server continues to proxy the TCP stream to and from the client. Note that only the initial connection request is HTTP - after that, the server simply proxies the established TCP connection.

Comment: I don't want to do "CONNECT" HTTP method by HTTP Proxy Server, maybe my proxy server can't support "CONNECT" HTTP method. So, could you tell me how to connect host by HTTPClient. I know SSLSocketFactory Class can connect SSL socket.